# Ionic project throws error only when building with --prod

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've a project that works fine(`ionic serve`, `ionic build` works fine), but when I trigger a

```
ionic build --prod
```

It fails with a lot of errors similar to this:

```
ERROR in src/app/explore/map/map.page.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'ion-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

just on basically all the ion-xxxx elements.

```
ionic info:
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.0 (C:\Users\julie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.6
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

What did I miss? Not sure how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: what ionic version are you using?? Please add result of `ionic info` to your question.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I just added ionic info